# Linking Parse and Facebook causes Facebook session to close

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my backend on my iOS application, and I am trying to use a `FBLoginView` to allow users to login with Facebook.

I am also trying to link the user's Facebook account to their Parse account. When I attempt to link the user to their FB by using

```
if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
        }
    }];
}
```

I receive an error telling me that the Facebook session is invalid. I have determined that the above code seems to be closing the Facebook session (when I comment out the code, the session does not close) and giving me the error. Does anyone have any experience with this error?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the user you're passing to the linkUser method a Parse account user or a Facebook user? I'm also trying to understand where FBLoginView comes into the picture.

Comment: @CAbernathy When the user clicks the FBLoginView, I want to check to see if they already have created a Parse account, and if so link their Facebook to their Parse Account. The user I am passing to linkUser is a PFUser.

Answer (score 0):

Do your other apps use Parse for the backend?

The user state stored in PFFacebookUtils is different from the user returned from the FBLoginView.

If your code looks like this:

```
#pragma mark FBLoginViewDelegate {
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    // link current user
    NSLog(@"User: %@", user);

    if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
        [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Then you are currently linking a Facebook user object with a PFUser, which are incompatible. I would suggest using the data that the FBLoginView returns, and creating a parse user in the conventional way:

```
#pragma mark FBLoginViewDelegate {
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    // link current user
    NSLog(@"User: %@", user);

    NSString *username = user[@"email"];
    NSString *password = user[@"id"];

    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"User: %@", user);
        if (error.code == 101) {
            // sign up
            PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
            user.username = username;
            user.password = password;
            [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Now [PFUser currentUser] will return a parse user object, that was created based on your Facebook login. If the app is deleted/reinstalled, the next time the user enters the app, the FBLoginView will return a userid that will be used to log in to parse as an existing user.

Edit: A similar issue I've had is with using FBLogin, PFFacebookUtils, and any other recent facebook app logins if my phone has Facebook integrated into iOS settings. It seems to have something to do with the Apple integration of Facebook, and the new Facebook SDKs. It's annoying but I have to currently tell my users to delete their facebook information from the Settings, then they can login, using either PFFacebookUtils, or the process above. I hope this gets resolved soon.

Comment: I am doing the latter. When the user clicks the FBLoginView, they are logged into Facebook. I then check if their Facebook email belongs to an existing Parse account. If it does, I want to give them the option to link the two right then and there. If they choose to link them at that time, I log in through Parse and attempt to link their Facebook account and Parse account. When I do this, the Facebook session is closed by `PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser` and the link fails.

Comment: You are trying to use two facebook libraries that were not built to work together. PFFacebookUtils handles its own Facebook session, and FBLoginView uses a different Facebook session. If you are using Parse and its FB utilities, stick to that. FBLoginView is good for returning you a dictionary of user information, ie facebook id, name, email, but it doesn't let the Facebook session handled by PFFacebookUtils know that a current active session has been created. So the best you can do to use both, is to create a regular parse user that has some attributes you've received from FBLoginView.

Comment: In other words, FBLoginView should be treated like another API, such as if you were logging in with a third party oauth. You'll get an authenticated user that you know is real, but PFFacebookUtils doesn't know about it.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I just assumed that since Parse is owned by Facebook, that the two would be fully compatible. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

for the first part of your question i'd found a way to login user into my app by just using Facebook with Parse. Actually once the users use this, you can check the data browser of your app and check the auth data filed and the profile filed with all the fb data that i did request within the app.

here is the code i use to login with fb, haven't linked a previous user with a fb account

```
 - (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender  {
// The permissions requested from the user
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    //[_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        //Go to your next view

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        //Go to your next view
    }
}];
```

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to use the FBLoginView to keep my app consistent with other apps that utilize Facebook integration. Is this code called when a custom button is clicked?

Comment: I was hoping to make use of the FBLoginView for consistency, but I may have to take your approach.

Comment: I did try it but i had a few issues and used it this way, it was kind of simpler, am glad my comment helped you!

Comment: I am using your code from above, and I am getting a Parse Error: The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid. (Code: 251, Version: 1.2.19). Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Haven't had that error, can you try to logout your user and then try to login again? or does it happens with all of your users?